# System of 4 equations:

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

There is a famous geometry problem named "Hardest easy problem" where we are required to find an angle(x). After drawing some lines and doing some calculations, I ended up with a system of 4 simulantaneous equations: I tried to solve it but I end up in identities,does this mean that i can't find the variables? The system:

Equation 1:        $a+x=70$

Equation 2:       $ x+y=110$

Equation 3:        $y+b=130$

Equation 4:      $  a+b=90$

Comment: We can get equation 4 from the previous three equations.

Comment: The solution to your system of equations is: $a = 90-b\color{grey}{\text{ and }}x = b-20\color{grey}{\text{ and }}y = 130-b$.

Comment: Is it impossible to find actual values for them? Their range of values is 10<Values<170

Answer (score 1):

They are only three equations since we can derive the last one from the above three(eq1-eq2+eq3). This means that we have infinitely many solutions of this system and we have a free variable say $x=r$ then
$$x=r\\a=70-r\\ y=110-r\\ b=130-y=20+r$$Now you can assume any value for $r$ and get a solution for your system.